# Right clicking on project doesn't show Git menu

Tags: git, android-studio, bitbucket

In Android Studio in the projects view when I right click on my project, I can't see the Git menu. Hence I can't add all the files altogether. How can I fix this?

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9nHGCFKtYlw) for bitbucket integration at `9:10` time.

My Android Studio version is 1.3.1 on xUbuntu 14.04 which shouldn't be a problem since the creator of the video posted it on 23rd Feb 2015 and this built was made on 3rd August 2015.

Comment: Is your project in a git repo?

Comment: @VonC Yes bitbucket, thanks for taking time to reply.

Comment: @VonC I've done the steps of git init and git remote, the Git menu will appear in VCS menu but not where I need it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem, unfortunately the path of root directory in Version Control settings was pointing to an inner directory.

Answer (score 4):

Go on top status bar and select in following order:

```
VCS > Enable Version Control Integration > select "Git"
```

Comment: See if you can re-import the project from git repository.

Comment: I'm new to GIT, do you want me to run the `git remote add` command again? That's how I previously added the repo.

Comment: So after doing git remote add, did you push it to remote repository?

Comment: Yeah, I manually did the `git add --all`, committed and pushed as well

Comment: Cool, go on VCS > Checkout from Version Control> Select Git/github, whichever is your remote repository. Give the Git Repository Url and checkout.

Comment: Its actually my own repo that I'd like to share with my team, do you still want me to checkout?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108167/discussion-between-devanshu-dwivedi-and-akash-aggarwal).